# Empty response on mutual likes graph explorer when user is not app admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm developing an Android app, based on facebook android SDK.
My app asks user_likes, user_friends, and read_friendlists permissions.
I'm trying to get mutual likes between two users with fql query (I can post it if you need but since it don't even work with graph explorer, fql is not the problem).

My fql request is  :

SELECT page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = 'uid1' and page_id IN ( SELECT page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = 'uid2').

Both uid1 and uid2 are registered app user, which have granted all permisions

If I execute this fql query from graph explorer on my account, the app administrator account, it works => I get the mutual likes ids

But if I execute this query from my test user, an account I created to test my app and wich have a test user role, I get an empty array.

I think my user access token is not enough to access other registered user's data, excepted my administrator user token.

But how could I get the results I need ? 
The app access token don't seem made for that, so what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

`user_likes` and `read_friendlists` need to get approved by Facebook or they will only be available to App Admins.

- Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- App Review Guidelines: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review